# Remove class from all div except the other two divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need help whenever i click on div with .clickable class .bg-color class will be added to span.aa and span.aaa and when i select option any other option like c other from other option .bg-color class will be removed i tried many other methods but its not working kindly help me get through this

```js
 $('.clickable').on('click',function(){
       $('.aa .aaa').removeClass('bg-color');
        $(this).addClass('bg-color');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="div input-group mb-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class=" aa input-group-text bor-clr" id="basic-addon1">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clickable input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aaa input-group-text  select-opt bor-clr ml-1" id="basic-addon1">Full time</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aa input-group-text bor-clr" id="basic-addon1">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clickable input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aaa input-group-text  select-opt bor-clr ml-1" id="basic-addon1">Part Time</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aa input-group-text bor-clr" id="basic-addon1">C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clickable input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aaa input-group-text  select-opt bor-clr ml-1" id="basic-addon1">Pinch</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aa input-group-text bor-clr" id="basic-addon1">D</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clickable input-group-prepend">
      <span class="aaa input-group-text  select-opt bor-clr ml-1" id="basic-addon1">Weekend Worrior</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Closing as typo: Use comma `$('.aa, .aaa')`

Comment: Aso, use `$(this).find(".aaa").addClass('bg-color');` since `.aaa` is child of `.clickable`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan agree, just a typo here.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: https://snipboard.io/hWyfNF.jpg  I tried but addClass is not working on span.aa

Comment: your `.find()` is not correct.

Comment: $('.clickable').on('click',function(){
       $('.aa , .aaa').removeClass('bg-color active-effect');
       $(this).find(".aaa, .aa").addClass('bg-color active-effect');
    }); @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Kindly correct me where it is not correct? @AlwaysHelping

Comment: `$('.clickable').on('click',function(){ $('.aa, .aaa').removeClass('bg-color active-effect'); $(this).find(".aaa").addClass('bg-color active-effect'); });` try this. working here: https://jsfiddle.net/wc9t3myL/2/

Comment: @AlwaysHelping class is adding on only span.aaa class also needs to be added on span.aa

Comment: Ok it works for me thanks for the help i put clickable class to the main div so other classes becomes child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting *elements which each has multiple classes*, it must be selecting *elements which each has one of these classes*. Below is a worked solution

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  $('.aa, .aaa').removeClass('bg-color')
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .find('.aa, .aaa')
    .addClass('bg-color')
})
```